# UILabel Multiple Lines

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a UILable which displays text as I press buttons. The text is from an attributed string. One of the buttons calls for a superscript attribute:

```
string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"A"];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(font) range:NSMakeRange(string.length-1, 1)];
[string addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:NSMakeRange(string.length-1, 1)];
[string2 appendSttributedString: string];
label.attributedText = string2;
```

This code works as long as string2 fits onto one line in the UILable. When the text begins to span two lines at first it appears as it should. However when the kCTSuperscriptAttributeName superscript attribute is added the second line of the label disappears and gets truncated. Im not sure whats going on. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are setting the `numberOfLines` property on the UILabel to be 2 or something, so that the label doesn't truncate beyond the first line. Hope this helps!

Comment: numberOfLines is set to 2. Initially the label wraps the text into two lines but when the superscript attribute is called it goes to one line and truncates. I even tried to set numberOfLines in code but it didnt help.

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your label so I can run it and see / fix the problem?

Comment: The code above is basically all there is to it. It is within a clicked button event and appends string to string2, which holds a collection of the text I want to display in my label. It is something about the superscript attribute that doesn't allow the text to be wrapped into two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName' for NSAttributedString?

```
     -(void)setText:(id)text withPrefixText:(id)prefixText andSuffixText:(id)suffixText
 {
NSString * compondText = [self textByCompoundingText:text withPrefixText:prefixText WithsuffixText:suffixText];
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedCompoundText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:compondText];

NSMutableDictionary * prefixTextAttributes = [@{} mutableCopy];
prefixTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName]  = _prefixTextFont? _prefixTextFont:self.font;
prefixTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = _prefixTextColour? _prefixTextColour:self.textColor;
NSNumber *baselineOffSet =[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:_prefixTextVerticalPositionning];
prefixTextAttributes[(NSString*)NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName] = baselineOffSet;

NSMutableDictionary * suffixTextAttributes = [@{} mutableCopy];
suffixTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName]  = _suffixTextFont? _suffixTextFont:self.font;
suffixTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = _suffixTextColour ?_suffixTextColour:self.textColor;
baselineOffSet = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:_suffixTextVerticalPostioning];
suffixTextAttributes[(NSString*)NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName] = baselineOffSet;
if(prefixText)
    [attributedCompoundText addAttributes:prefixTextAttributes  range:[compondText rangeOfString:prefixText]];
if(suffixText)
    [attributedCompoundText addAttributes:suffixTextAttributes  range:[compondText rangeOfString:suffixText]];
self.attributedText = attributedCompoundText;
}
```